# why Golang handle cutoff in atoi.go like this?

Tags: go, overflow, atoi

```
// code in atoi.go, line 90
var cutoff uint64
switch base {
case 10:
    cutoff = maxUint64/10 + 1
case 16:
    cutoff = maxUint64/16 + 1
default:
    cutoff = maxUint64/uint64(base) + 1
}
```

I saw some code in file atoi.go of Golang package, why not write it like below?

```
var cutoff = maxUint64/uint64(base) + 1
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's faster for the (by far) most common uses.

Answer (score 6):

I think the [comment above](https://golang.org/src/strconv/atoi.go?s=5658:5690#L105) the line you are referring to may answer your question:

> // Use compile-time constants for common cases.

Because `maxUint64/10 + 1` and `maxUint64/16 + 1` only reference constants the compiler can calculate this. The result is that there is no need to perform the division operation at runtime every time `ParseUint` is called. You can see the benchmarks in the [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/06ed8f0df76e9b0256de286392d42d1ea7dec809).